# JVM failed to start: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/libexec/StartupItemContext; error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, glassfish, ioexception, asadmin

In my **OS X Yosemite**, I'm trying to **start-domain** in terminal:

```
sh asadmin start-domain mythMobile
```

and I get error:

```
JVM failed to start: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/libexec/StartupItemContext" (in directory "/Applications/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/mythMobile/config"): error=2, No such file or directory
Command start-domain failed.
```

This problem appeared after I've installed **beta Yosemite** on my mac. **Before** I had Mavericks, everything worked correctly.

Have anybody faced with such problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple removed the file under OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). Unfortunately the path to the file is hard coded within the GlassFish startup code (GFLauncher.java) and not configurable.

The GlassFish team is already aware of the issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21113

I hope there will be a fix for GlassFish 3 as well, since we still use it in production.

GFLauncher Code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.admin/launcher/3.1.1/com/sun/enterprise/admin/launcher/GFLauncher.java?av=f

Comment: The issue is RESOLVED (https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21113).
Fix Version/s: 4.0.1, 4.1

Comment: Hey, did you guys created the file StartupItemContext.sh ? I putted the file in both paths already /usr/libexec/ and in /domains/domain1/config/ I can't make it run GF in eclipse ! :'( help, please

Comment: Create the file /usr/libexec/StartupItemContext as described in GLASSFISH-21113, and make sure it is executable:
`chmod +x /usr/libexec/StartupItemContext`

Answer (score 47):

To work-around that, you can start GF in verbose mode using:

```
asadmin start-domain --verbose domain1
```

Comment: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15118 Why not to use the --verbose option.

Comment: How can I set this in IntelijIDEA IDE run configuration ?

Comment: @SiamandMaroufi You can set the command used to start the Glassfish server in the Run configurations see the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/rLgE4oP.png)

Comment: I've tried `asadmin start-domain domain1 --verbose` as stated in other solutions here, but this is the ONLY correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the entire current version of glassfih4 folder solved my issue on OS X 10.11.3.
Then I simply ran in ../glassfish4/galssfish/ `sudo ./bin/asadmin start-domain` and then it worked again...